# Inheritance component class other than React.Component is throwing "Super expression must either be null or a function" exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to inherit my Components from a BaseComponent. BaseComponent intern inherit from React.Component.

Here is how I am doing.

- BaseComponent is inherited from React.Component
- Screen is inherited from BaseComponent
- Section is inherited from BaseComponent

Section component is used in the render method of Screen Component. When I try to run my App. I am getting "

> Super expression must either be null or a function

exception.

If I change my Section component inheritance to React.Component my App is rendering properly.

Please find my components below:

BaseComponent.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import ActionHandler from '../ActionHandler';
import {Mapper} from '../ComponentMapper';

export default class BaseComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.actionHandler = new ActionHandler();
 }

 getComponentName(data) {
  return Mapper[data.type].component;
 }
}
```

Screen.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import BaseComponent from '../BaseComponent';

import Header from '../Header';
import Section from './Section';
import CustomButton from '../controls/CustomButton';

import resolver from '../../ComponentDataResolver';

export default class Screen extends BaseComponent {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

 getHeaderNode() {
  //return <Header title="Native App" style={styles.header}></Header>;
  return React.createElement(Header, {title: "Native App", style: styles.header});
 }

 getMainNode(data) {
  let componentData = resolver.getComponentData(data);
  let componentName = this.getComponentName(componentData);
  return (
   <View style={styles.containerScrollable}>
    {<Section data={componentData} />}
    {/*React.createElement(componentName, componentData)*/}
   </View>
  );
 }

 getScreenNode() {
  var elements = [];
  //elements.push(this.getHeaderNode());
  elements.push(React.createElement(Header, {title: "Native App", style: styles.header}));
  if (this.props.data && this.props.data.children) {
   let children = this.props.data.children;
   for (let index in children) {
    switch (children[index].type) {
     case "HEADER":
      elements.push(this.getHeaderNode());
      break;
     case "CENTER":
      elements.push(this.getMainNode(children[index].children[0]));
      break;
    }
   }
  }
  return elements;
 }

 /*
  getScreenNode() {
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     {this.getScreenNode()}
     <View style={styles.footer}>
      <CustomButton style={styles.button} title="Submit" onPressHandler={this.actionHandler.clickHandler} />
     </View>
    </View>);
  }*/

 render() {
  return this.getScreenNode();
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
 },
 containerScrollable: {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: 8,
  overflow: 'scroll'
 },
 header: {
  backgroundColor: '#0747A6',
  color: 'white',
  height: 56,
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  textAlign: 'center',
 },
 footer: {
  backgroundColor: '#0747A6',
  height: 40,
  alignContent: 'flex-end'
 },
 button: {
  color: '#2B52FF',
  height: 40
 }
});
```

Section.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import BaseComponent from '../BaseComponent';

import resolver from '../../ComponentDataResolver';
import Mapper from '../../ComponentMapper';

export default class Section extends BaseComponent {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

 getScreenNode() {
  var elements = [];
  //elements.push(this.getHeaderNode());
  elements.push(<Text>Sample Text</Text>);
  return elements;
 }

 render() {
  return this.getScreenNode();
 }
}
```

Please find the screenshot below:
[image]